Problems with COPY EXEC command
A very simple Docker Compose on Ubuntu, which shares a folder and runs a script a couple of times a day using nodemon. But I am getting the following error:FROM ubuntu:22.04
 => CACHED [app  5/10] WORKDIR /usr/src/app                                                                                                                                                 0.0s
 => CACHED [app  6/10] COPY package*.json ./                                                                                                                                                0.0s
 => CACHED [app  7/10] RUN npm install                                                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => CACHED [app  8/10] COPY shared/ /usr/src/app/shared/                                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => CACHED [app  9/10] COPY entrypoint.sh /usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => CACHED [app 10/10] RUN chmod +x /usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh                                                                                                                              0.0s
 => [app] exporting to image                                                                                                                                                                0.0s
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                                                                                     0.0s
 => => writing image sha256:7264678cee85d1163592c006c133092ecdf0ae7d37e186668ce32d481489f8c8                                                                                                0.0s
 => => naming to docker.io/library/pricer-app                                                                                                                                               0.0s
[+] Running 1/0
 ✔ Container nodejs_app  Created                                                                                                                                                            0.0s 
Attaching to nodejs_app
nodejs_app  | exec /usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh: no such file or directory
nodejs_app exited with code 1

I cheked via : docker-compose run app /bin/bash
ls -l /usr/src/app.   Answer  exec /usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh: no such file or directory
I checked the presence of the file, applied chmod, and created the directory, but I don’t understand what I’m doing wrong ???
My Dockerfile
#  Node.js, npm и cron
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
  curl \
  cron \
  && curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_20.x | bash - \
  && apt-get install -y lsb-release gnupg > /dev/null 2>&1 \
  && apt-get install -y nodejs
RUN npm install -g nodemon
RUN mkdir -p -m=755 /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY shared/ /usr/src/app/shared/
COPY entrypoint.sh /usr/src/app/
RUN chmod +x /usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh"]

Only 3 files in my folder: entrypoint.sh Dockerfile and simple compose.yml
entrypoint.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo "0 11 * * * /usr/local/bin/nodemon /usr/src/app/shared/send.js" >> /etc/crontabs/root
echo "0 23 * * * /usr/local/bin/nodemon /usr/src/app/shared/send.js" >> /etc/crontabs/root
crond
nodemon /usr/src/app/shared/send.js

compose file
services:
  app:
    build: .
    container_name: nodejs_app
    volumes:
      - ./shared:/usr/src/app/shared
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
   
    entrypoint: ["/usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh"] 


What is the Dockerfile's FROM line, and what is the very first "shebang" line of the script?  (Are you trying to use a script that says it needs bash on an Alpine-based image that doesn't have it; can it use a POSIX shell instead?  Is there any chance the script has DOS line endings?)

If you're on an Ubuntu host, you should be able to sudo apt-get install nodejs to get a local Node installation, at which point you can delete pretty much everything you show in the question.  Do you actually need to isolate your development tools inside containers?

try to build with parameter --no-cache ... as per docker build --tag footag --no-cache . also you may want to remove the build from your compose file and build your docker image as a distinct step  ... do this once with cache shut off just to wipe stale image layers then remove mention of no-cache and build again and you should be good
